# Objectify: adding the @Cache annotation on existing data and removing @Parent

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

Two questions about updating my domain diagram:

1) I am new to GAE and have just deployed my first application based on Objectify. Just to discover than soon after my first users came in I had soon gone through the datastore read quota limit:

[image: snapshot fron datastore viewer]

I had not until now put too much thought on server side caching. I thought Objectify's session cache would do the job for me. But now I realise I need use the global memcache.

According to Objectify's doc, I have to use Objectify's `@Cache` annotation on every entity that is accessed by key (and not by query).

However I am concerned about the side effects this will have on data that I have already stored in datastore.

2) I also realize now that I am using `@Parent` too much. There are a couple entities were using `@Parent` has no benefit (and it has some drawbacks due the datastore limiting write operations on entities belonging to the same root).

If I go ahead and remove the `@Parent` annotation from the entities of my domain where it no longer is needed, will it have side effects on the already persited entities?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- For objectify : the global cache is enabled by default, however you
  must still annotate your entity classes with @Cache.
- @Parent is
  important if you need consistent result, and avoid [eventual
  consistency](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/structuring_for_strong_consistency). Removing the ancestor will have a side effect on the already stored data    as the key will change. You will need a migration plan.

But most of all, the free quota are quite reasonable, so if you already run into quota errors with your first user, then I would suggest installing [appstats](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/appstats) and actually measure what is the real underlying cause i.e. what action(s) are responsible for the bulk of the operations and work on those. Much better than a general approach.

Comment: Thaks for the answering. Caching my entities is already helping reducing costs. Now the biggest impact on cost are queries. I have also installed appstats as suggested, since I use RequestFactory, all the operations are logged as POST /gwtRequest which does not allow me to debug which is the exact server call that is adding cost. I guess that is beyond the scope of appstats, righ?

Comment: @manubot you can always drill down into each request with appstats, no matter how you make the calls to the backend. You get very detailed information on each datastore activity, bandwith usage etc..

Comment: agreed, it is great the level of detail. However since RequestFactory does all the request to the /gwtRequest servlet, I do not know exactly to which of my server's API function every entry on appstats corresponds to.